# Archive feature in bolt cms

Tags: symfony, bolt-cms

I am new to bolt cms and trying to solve this last problem. I have entries content type but the client wants to archive an entry and it be moved to the archived content type. Is there a way to do this? I am going to try to find devs who work on bolt extensions because I am not sure if I can get this to work. So my main question is how can one duplicate an entry and have it moved out of entries content type over to the archives content type? Any direction or thoughts are welcome because I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Some  years ago i did extinsion with something  like this
if  worked on cron - listener attached to cron::daily.

Basicly it's all about database operations ,you can have "archive" as a  taxonomy category (or  tag)  and  only thing that you need  to do is to change relation in content  you want to archive ...

below  you have link to my old  script   , it's a  mess - i know  , but  it  works .  maybe you'll be able to take something from it (it was designed for my content types)

https://gist.github.com/poznet/98269b3995c75d6f9b49583bfa55e191

Comment: You are awesome! Do you mind telling me what language the comments are so I can translate them? Also, where do I put this? If you don't mind me asking. I can pay you if you want to email me. jojoclark @ gmail